# copy data between 2 databases with same tables, but different identities

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables `Listings` and  `Media` which is a child table of `Listings` and linked based on `ListingId` in "source" database, and I have the same tables in "destination" dabase.

copy all listings to destination table Listings and its children to destination `Media` table
keeping in mind that the destination `Media` table has to get the `ListingId` of what was inserted to the destination `Listings` table and that is a `identity column`

```
INSERT INTO Listings ( Title, ...)
SELECT  Title..
FROM [source].[dbo].Listings
WHERE ListingId IN (
    SELECT s.ListingId
    FROM [source].[dbo].Listings s
    LEFT JOIN Listings d ON s.ImportedReferenceNumber = d.ImportedReferenceNumber
    WHERE d.ListingId IS NULL
);

-- Insert corresponding media records into destination.Media table with new ListingIds.
INSERT INTO Media ( ListingId, Url, ThumbnailUrl, TypeId)
SELECT New.ListingID, Url, ThumbnailUrl, TypeId
FROM [source].[dbo].Media m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.ListingId, d.ListingId AS NEW_ListingId
    FROM [source].[dbo].Listings s
    LEFT JOIN Listings d ON s.ImportedReferenceNumber = d.ImportedReferenceNumber
    WHERE d.ListingId IS NULL
) AS NEW ON m.ListingId = NEW.ListingId;
```

The first part works fine, but nothing gets inserted into destination `Media` because the query I have when executed, there is no difference between source and destination `Listings` table

Comment: Table DDLs, sample data and expected results would go a long way in helping you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a simple loop and SCOPE_IDENTITY(), but depending on the size of your data set, could run for quite some time.

Also, for any hope of this finishing, you need to have a nonclustered index on Media.ListingId.

```
 DECLARE @ListingId_Orig BIGINT,
        @ListingId_Max BIGINT,
        @ListingId_New BIGINT = 0
        

SELECT @ListingId_Orig = MIN(ListingId) FROM [source].[dbo].Listings WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT @ListingId_Max = MAX(ListingId) FROM [source].[dbo].Listings WITH (NOLOCK)

WHILE @ListingId_Orig <= @ListingId_Max

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Listings ( Title, ...)
SELECT Title, ...
FROM [source].[dbo].Listings
WHERE ListingId IN (
    SELECT s.ListingId
    FROM [source].[dbo].Listings s
    LEFT JOIN Listings d ON s.ImportedReferenceNumber = d.ImportedReferenceNumber
    WHERE d.ListingId IS NULL
)
AND ListingId = @ListingId_Orig -- Ensure only one row is selected. 

SELECT @ListingId_New = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


-- Insert corresponding media records into destination.Media table with new ListingIds based on identity value of prior insert using SCOPE_IDENTITY(). 
INSERT INTO Media ( ListingId, Url, ThumbnailUrl, TypeId)
SELECT @ListingId_New, Url, ThumbnailUrl, TypeId
FROM [source].[dbo].Media m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.ListingId, d.ListingId AS NEW_ListingId
    FROM [source].[dbo].Listings s
    LEFT JOIN Listings d ON s.ImportedReferenceNumber = d.ImportedReferenceNumber
    WHERE d.ListingId IS NULL
) AS NEW ON m.ListingId = NEW.ListingId
WHERE m.ListingId = @ListingId_Orig


IF @ListingID = @ListingId_Max
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    
SELECT TOP 1 @ListingId = ListingId FROM [source].[dbo].Listings WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ListingID > @ListingId

END
```

This works by inserting records from the source Listings table into the target Listings table one by one, using SCOPE_IDENTITY() to capture the Identity value of the newly inserted record in the @ListingID_New variable, then inserting into the child Media table ONLY records from the original Media table that have a ListingId that matches the ListingId that was just inserted into the target Listings table, and setting the ListingID for the target Media table using the @ListingID_New value.